# How to force tu use RTCPeerConnection from AdapterJS

Tags: node.js, angular, webrtc

I tried to add RTCPeerConnection from adapterJS, but my typescript wouldn't allow me to do that.
Always import from lib.es6 instead off adapterJS.

I installed adapterJS via this command  npm install webrtc-adapter --save

And I tried to do sth like this:

```
import RTCPeerConnection from 'webrtc-adapter';
```

or

```
import adapter from 'webrtc-adapter';
```

But it always fails.

What I'm doing wrong guys?

Comment: Did you find out? Please answer your own question to help me and others.

Comment: @HermanFransen Yea, please have a look on my answer, now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was totally misunderstanding!

Adapter is working out of the box, it's the layer between my component and the javascript interpreter in browser.

So adapter is working fine, I don'w have to import them.

All I have to do is `import 'webrtc';` in typings.d.ts